# placing links on background image

Tags: javascript, html

I want to place links over a background image (set in CSS) and I want to ask is there an alternative to the map tag ? an HTML5 or elegant JS solution ?

Note: the image itself is not a map. I just want to place 5 links on specific positions

thanks

Comment: a background image for what element ? can you include you HTML / CSS ?

Comment: You could catch the mouse coordinates when an onclick event on that div that is holding the background image is triggered. Depending on the coordinates you can load a different page. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: You can add any number of <a> tags that have no content - set them to display:block or inline-block and just set the sizes on them and use absolute positioning to put them where you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would NEVER recommend using the map tag. You lose all SEO value of doing so. I recommend you use a similar syntax:

```
<div id="backgroundElement">
 <a href="#" id="link1">Follow Me on Twitter</a>
 <a href="#" id="link2">Follow Me on Facebook</a>
 <a href="#" id="link2">Follow Me on Google+</a>
</div>
```

and in the CSS use

```
#backgroundElement{ position:relative; background:url(image/bg.jpg) no-repeat; }
#link1{ position:absolute; top:150px; left:200px; background:url(image/icon/twitter.png) no-repeat; height:24px; width:24px; display:block; text-indent:-9999em; }
```

The links top and left will determine it's location on the background. Ensure the height and width is set, and that the display block and text-indent is set to remove the text and format it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If your links are rectangular, then the easy solution is to use `position:absolute` links on a `position:relative` background.

If your links are non-rectangular, then you can catch the click() event on the background element and then do the appropriate action if the coordinates match your "hot" area.

See http://jsfiddle.net/STjfz/2/ for a code sample of both techniques.